# How can i append all the elements of an array to a div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, appendchild

The below shows what my current source is, but this only seems to add the last object in my array to my div, how can i add all the objects to my div.

```
    ajaxHelper.processRequest((response: Array<Vehicle.Vehicle>) => {
        console.log(response);
        var divVehicles = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("divVehicleResults");
        var label = <HTMLLabelElement>document.createElement("label");
        for (let vehicle of response) {
            label.innerHTML = vehicle.id;
            divVehicles.appendChild(label);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's because you're re-using the same label object. You need `var label = ...` inside the loop.

Comment: ahhh well spotted, that sorted it for me thanks, you can place it in the answers so i can mark it @approxiblue

Comment: @ifelabolz Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As approxiblue said, right now you are reusing the same label object.  You should put `var label = ...` inside the loop to create a new label each time (and thereby append new labels, as you requested).

**Corrected Code:**

```
ajaxHelper.processRequest((response: Array<Vehicle.Vehicle>) => {
    console.log(response);
    var divVehicles = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("divVehicleResults");

    for (let vehicle of response) {
        var label = <HTMLLabelElement>document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = vehicle.id;
        divVehicles.appendChild(label);
    }
});
```